# How to export the ignored files by retaining the folders structure in Git?

Tags: git, export, gitignore, extract

I have a project, where I want to separate the (not versioned / `.gitignore`d) files (the most of them are config files) from the actual source code. I want to copy them to a directories structure identical to the project's directories structure. E.g.:

```
/foo
/bar/config/env.xml <-- ignored
/bar/config/env.xml.dist
/buz/keys <-- ignored
/buz/logs <-- ignored
/buz/source

$ git extract-ignored-files --exclude-from-extracting=/buz/logs (pseudocode)
Aimed result:

/bar/config/env.xml <-- ignored
/buz/keys <-- ignored
```

The concrete requirement behind it is to be able to transfer settings from one system to another (and set up this another one quickly by adapting only a couple of settings).

**How to export the `.gitignore`d files?** In the best case I also would like (1) to keep there by the folders' structure identical to the original structure and (2) be able to exclude some paths from the extracting result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Define the paths, you want to transfer. It will be a subset of the set of the ignored files.**

This can be done various ways, e.g. by reviewing the `.gitignore` and transforming its rules to paths or by using `git status --ignored` or `git check-ignore *`. I prefer this way:

a. Get all `.gitignore`d files (`git ls-files --others > ./transfer-excludes.txt`) (in my case I got a file with about `22k` lines).

b. Define from the result file's entries manually the patterns you *don't* (!) want to transfer. It can be for example your IDE settings, the folder with the external libraries, logs etc. -- everything you definitely won't need to copy to another project instance.

**2. Get the paths to be transferred.**

```
$ git ls-files --others --exclude-from=./transfer-excludes.txt > ./transfer-files.txt
```

The approach might need some more effort. But then all possible ignore paths (including the ones excluded by the sub-directories' `.gitignore`s) become visible and can be checked.

**3. Copy the files.**

It's just a simple bash script, that scans the paths, creates the needed directories structure (by using `mkdir -p`), and copies the files:

```
#!/bin/bash
INFILE="./transfer-files.txt"
TARGETROOT="./transfer"
while read line
do
    TARGETDIR=`dirname $line`
    TARGETPATH="${TARGETROOT}/${TARGETDIR}"
    if [ ! -d "${TARGETPATH}" ]
    then
        mkdir -p "${TARGETPATH}"
    fi
    # echo ${TARGETPATH}
    cp "$line" "${TARGETPATH}"
done < ${INFILE}
```

The `cp --parents` instead of the combination of `mkdir -p` and `cp` doesn't work in this case, since it cannot crate complete path recursively, if it's not there yet.

```
$ ./transfer.sh
```

That's it.

---

**A little check:**

```
$ find ./transfer/ -type f -exec du -a {} +
```

The output should equal to the list of the files from the `transfer-files.txt`.

**Possible improvements:**

- The steps `2` and `3` can be merged to script. (But sometimes you won't want to, in order to have a chance to check the file list first.)
- Another improvement idea: It would be possible to create Git hook, that checks, wheter the commit affects a `.gigitnore` file -- in this case the `transfer-excludes.txt` should be updated.

Answer (score 1):

The `--parents` flag to cp will maintain directory structure.

```
mkdir ignored_files
  for x in `git status --ignored .`; do
  cp -va --parents $x ignored_files/$x
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it doesn't work for me. Maybe because the output of the `git status --ignored .` doesn't consist of a pure list of the paths, but also includes some text information.

Comment: The `.` means current directory. You can replace with any path.

Comment: It's not about the current path (`.`). When you execute `git status --ignored` (with or without path parameter), you'll see, what I mean. There is some text before the paths list.

Comment: `git status --ignored --short | cut -f2 -d' '` or `git status --ignored --short | awk '{print $2}'`. But the best of all `git ls-files --others`

Comment: Got it, My ignore list is huge and I didn't scroll all the way up.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon `git ls-files --ignored` ->
 `fatal: ls-files --ignored needs some exclude pattern`

Answer (score 1):

[`rsync -R`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) preserves relative path names:

```
rsync -aR `git ls-files --others` ignored_files/
```